# c++ extern template instantiation and typedef (gcc)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

I am trying to instantiate a template externaly however I would like o use a typedef in the instantiation clause. I think the example says more than thousand words:

```
typedef myTemplate_base<commonValue> myTemplate; //in 99% of the cases I use this so I want a shorthand
extern template class myTemplate; //wont work/compiler error class infront of typedef
```

I get the same error if I try to actually instantiate the template like this:

```
template class myTemplate;
```

I know I can write `(extern) template class myTemplate_base<commonValue>` instead, however I think this is uglier, since I need to adjust my common Value in 3 places instead of one.

So how do I have to put this, to use the typedef in the extern declaration/instantiation?

I am ussing gcc 4.6.1 on Ubunutu

Comment: So you're question is... that you think the C++ syntax is ugly? Tell us something we didn't know...

Comment: dont feed the trolls...
well I think it is pretty much fine/functional however I was wondering hy I could not instantiate from typedefs, thats all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*typedef-name* cannot be used in explicit instantiation.

From 14.7.2/3

> If the explicit instantiation is for a class or member class, the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* in the *declaration* shall include a
>   *simple-template-id*. If the explicit instantiation is for a function or
>   member function, the *unqualifiedid* in the declaration shall be either
>   a *template-id* or, where all template arguments can be deduced, a
>   *template-name* or *operator-function-id*. ...

Comment: thank you very much. Every time I come to stackoverflow I am surprised bey the amount of c++StandardGurus here.

Comment: @ted I suspect this is just bjarne using hundreds of different usernames

Answer (score 2):

Use a `constexpr` or a `typedef` for your common value. Then you only have to change the common value once and all the explicit instantiations will change.

That's about the best you can do. You are not allowed to do an explicit instantiation using a `tyepdef` name.